# e2e tests fail on server with selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I'm about to create an application full js based on [vuejs](/questions/tagged/vuejs). Following https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack, I have started a project:

```
$ vue init webpack my-project && cd my-project && yarn install
```

When I run unittest `yarn run unit` everything goes well, but when I run `yarn run e2e` which runs [nightwatch.js](/questions/tagged/nightwatch.js), I get this error:

```
> Starting dev server...

Starting to optimize CSS...
> Listening at http://localhost:8889

Starting selenium server... started - PID:  23451
started - PID:  23451

[Test] Test Suite
=====================

Running:  default e2e tests

[client :: capabilities] Test Suite
=======================================


Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server

Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
{ Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:344:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:436:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1047:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' }

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) server is started on the fly when the [e2e](/questions/tagged/e2e) tests start and is shutdown when they finish. I'm sure because when I stop [nightwatch.js](/questions/tagged/nightwatch.js) before it fails I see :

```
$ ps aux | grep -i selenium
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver -jar node_modules/selenium-server/lib/runner/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -port 4444
```

So the real error based on the output I get is mostlikely `Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server`. How do I fix this?

#### package.json

```
"chromedriver": "^2.27.2",
"cross-spawn": "^5.0.1",
"nightwatch": "^0.9.12",
"selenium-server": "^2.53.1",
```

#### test/e2e/nightwatch.conf.js

```
require('babel-register')
var config = require('../../config')

// http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted#settings-file
module.exports = {
  src_folders: ['test/e2e/specs'],
  output_folder: 'test/e2e/reports',
  custom_assertions_path: ['test/e2e/custom-assertions'],

  selenium: {
    start_process: true,
    server_path: require('selenium-server').path,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 4444,
    cli_args: {
      'webdriver.chrome.driver': require('chromedriver').path
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently started a Vue.js project with Webpack template. Your problem sounds familiar, but surprisingly, I forgot how I solved it...

The only difference I can see between your `package.json` and mine is the `selenium-server` version (`^3.0.1`). You should also check your Node version because Nightwatch is based on it. I remember that I had to update Node and npm for some reason (I do not use Yarn).

This is my environment (and it is working fine):

- **Node.js** (v8.1.3)
- **npm** (5.0.3)

Comment: I cannot use the version `^3.0.1` of `selenium-server` because the server that selenium will run on has `java 1.7`. What headless browsers are you using?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you are trying to do... By default, E2E tests are executed on Chrome if you create a new project with vue-cli. It is not a headless browser: here you automate a true instance of Chrome. If you want to run some high-level tests on a remote server, you would certainly need PhantomJS (+ CasperJS). But in Vue.js, PhantomJS is already used with Karma for unit testing.

Comment: that's the problem then!! because I'm trying to execute e2e tests on a remote server to automate them, so no GUI at all. And if I understood you right, it's not possible to run e2e tests on remote server which does not have a GUI?

Comment: Nightwatch.js is an E2E testing framework which is based on Selenium/WebDriver. This technology has been designed to automate graphical web browsers like Firefox or Chrome. If you do not want to test a GUI in real conditions, you can use Nightwatch.js with PhantomJS (a true headless browser), but this is not the most common use case (I would rather recommend CasperJS here). Outside your Vue project, have you ever used a browser automation library like Nightwatch or WebdriverIO? When you run a test suite, a new window is created and you can **see** in real time what happens in the browser... :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `node nightwatch.config.js`, or `node {whatever your nightwatch config file is called}`. This will install `Selenium` and `ChromeDriver` correctly.